# (TS) Generic type 'Subject<T>' requires 1 type argument(s)

Tags: angular, datatables, angular-datatables

I am trying to set up Angular Datatables, the Angular Way with Angular 6 and am getting an error that none of the docs seem to address.

> (TS) Generic type 'Subject' requires 1 type argument(s)

This is what appears when I hover over "Subject" in

```
dtTrigger: Subject = new Subject();
```

I have all of the imports as shown in the example. Is there a newer example or maybe I need to update something in Angular? I had to do that for a different error that is now resolved.

I am following this example:  https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/basic/angular-way

Comment: `dtTrigger: Subject<any> = new Subject();` : you have to type the data of the subject. If you know what type of data you will send, use it, otherwise use any.

Answer (score 2):

```
dtTrigger: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();
```

working in angular and angular datatable 8

Answer (score 0):

You should type your subject, Try this:

```
private $dtTrigger<any> = new Subject<any>();
```

Comment: I found a newer? example that might be the answer:  dtTrigger: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();